# Unable to upload image on firebase due to Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class error

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

I am trying to upload an image by selecting it from the gallery of my phone. But after selecting it does nothing at all even don't upload it.

I have tried clean build and rebuild still it doesn't help.

It just disconnect automatically by saying :

> V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress D/FA: Connected to remote
>   service V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2 V/FA: Inactivity,
>   disconnecting from the service

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button uploadButton;
    ImageView downloadedImage;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE=1;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    //private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uploadButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        downloadedImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        //progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                Log.i("Done","Till here");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && requestCode == RESULT_OK)
        {

            Log.i("Not Done","This log is not visible");

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child("Photo").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    //progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Uploaded...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });


        }
    }
}
```

The error which I am getting is :

> I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;

Comment: change `if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && requestCode == RESULT_OK)` to `if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE&& resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)` and try

Comment: Log.i("dataUri",uri.toString()); Check the value of dataUri.

Comment: @Raj I am not able to get to the part inside the if loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change requestCode to resultCode after && and it will work.

```
if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
}
```